# Recover data from old working RAID 1 disk

Tags: debian, raid, mdadm, raid1

I am running a system with Debian 12. `/root/` is on a RAID1 array with `mdadm` with 2 mirrored SSD (let's call them disks A and B). All disks are perfectly functioning.

I wanted to replace the two A and B SSDs with larger SSDs (let's call them X and Y).

I have swapped A with X simply by unplugging A and plugging X and then adding X back to the RAID array. It synced and everything was working.

I then tried to grow the RAID array with `mdadm` but I have made some typos and broke the array (the superblock is not consistent anymore).

How can I recover data from disk A, given that it is perfectly working? I am afraid of trying anything myself as I don't want to lose any data.

Comment: "_I then tried to grow the RAID array with mdadm but I have made some typos_" - this should be in your shell's `history`. What _exactly_ did you type and how did that break the system?

Comment: It was done using gparted live USB. No history unfortunately.